# How to get UITableViewCell from the handle function of UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: uitableview

I add UIImageView in the UITavleViewCell, and add UITapGestureRecognizer for UIImageView, how can i get the UITableViewCell in UITap event handle function `(void)likeImageTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap`?

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"TextCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    };

    UIImageView* likeImage = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kLikeImage];
    [likeImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *likeImageTap =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(likeImageTap:)];
    [likeImageTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [likeImage addGestureRecognizer:likeImageTap];

    return cell;
}


- (void)likeImageTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap {
    // How cam i get UITableViewCell?
    UIImageView* likeImageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:kLikeImage];
    [likeImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_liked"]];
}
```

Comment: take a custom button same property of UIImageView...

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint loc = [tap locationInView:self.tableView];
for (UITableViewCell* cell in self.tableView.visibleCells){
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(cell.frame, loc)){
        // cell is the cell you're after
    }
}
```